# Matplotlib plot a graph with changing formula

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I basically have some data which is like this: `x = [0, 5, 12, 17]` and `y = [0, 1, 0, 0]` (I mean those are really long lists). Now I would like to plot a graph which has value of `0` from `0` to `5`, then from `5` to `12` -> `1`, and then from `12` to `17` the value of `0`. Now I can do this by generating an arrays like this:
`x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]` and `y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...., 0]` and just `plt.plot(x,y)`. But for large arrays this is not efficient I guess, so I would like to ask if there is a `matplotlib` method to print specified value or function formula within a specified range? (like `sin(x)` from `0` to `5` and something else further)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting the example data can be done using `plt.step`. In this case, the argument `where` must be `where="post"`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 5, 12, 17]
y = [0, 1, 0, 0]

plt.step(x, y, where='post', label='step')
plt.xticks(x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did not understand the part in the question which suddenly talks about functions, so I left that out of my answer.

Comment: Yes, it was unnecessary. Thank you!